# Python multiprocessing SyncManager/AutoProxy appears not to update shared object correctly

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

python3; I have an object with a function that adds an item to a list, the list is an attribute of the object. If I allow a `Process` to access this via a `SyncManager`, then calling the function on the `AutoProxy` object that the `SyncManager` gives me doesn't actually modify the underlying state of the list except within the scope of the member function.

How do I observe the expected new state of `q.tasks` in the following code?:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager

class MyQueue:
    """ A task queue (not fully functional or actually thread safe) """
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = []

    def add_task(self, t):
        """ Just adds t to self.tasks """
        print("Adding '%s' to queue   %r which has ID %r" % (t, self, id(self)))
        self.tasks.append(t)
        print("After add the task list is: %s" % (self.tasks))

# Instance of MyQueue and a manager object to allow other processes to read it
q = MyQueue()
class QManager(SyncManager):
    pass
QManager.register('get_q', callable=lambda: q)
key = bytes([1,2,3,4,5,6])
man = QManager(('localhost', 5000), key)

def create_tasks(addr, key):
    """ Add some tasks to the queue """
    class ServerQueueManager(SyncManager):
        pass
    ServerQueueManager.register('get_q')
    manager = ServerQueueManager(address=addr, authkey=key)
    manager.connect()
    my_q = manager.get_q()
    print(type(my_q))
    my_q.add_task('foo')

man.start()

# Show details before
print("MAIN PROC: The queue is %r which has ID %r" % (q, id(q)))
print("MAIN PROC: Before add, task list is: %s" % q.tasks)
# Run the adder process to completion
p = Process(target=create_tasks, args=(('localhost', 5000), key))
p.start()
p.join()
# Show details after
print("MAIN PROC: The queue is %r which has ID %r" % (q, id(q)))
print("MAIN PROC: After add,  task list is: %s" % q.tasks)

man.shutdown()
```

This code results in the following output:

```
MAIN PROC: The queue is <__main__.MyQueue object at 0x7f474940e0b8> which has ID 139944148394168
MAIN PROC: Before add, task list is: []
<class 'multiprocessing.managers.AutoProxy[get_q]'>
Adding 'foo' to queue   <__main__.MyQueue object at 0x7f474940e0b8> which has ID 139944148394168
After add the task list is: ['foo']
MAIN PROC: The queue is <__main__.MyQueue object at 0x7f474940e0b8> which has ID 139944148394168
MAIN PROC: After add,  task list is: []
```

Answer (score 0):

This is some kind of quirk of the SyncManager that I don't fully understand,

But a workaround is to have the main thread also connect to the manager to get the queue instance in the same way that the sub-process does, and to have a getter function in the Queue class for getting the tasks:

```
class MyQueue:
    ...
    def get_tasks(self):
        return self.tasks

...

manager = ServerQueueManager(address=addr, authkey=key)
manager.connect()
my_q = manager.get_q()
print(my_q.get_tasks())
```

The getter is only needed because the proxy class doesn't allow you to access attributes directly, only functions. An alternative would be to use a custom proxy class. This is slightly more complicated so not explained here.